# How in C to get the name of the shared library a symbol is loaded from programatically at runtime?

Tags: c, dlsym

I load a symbol from a shared library like this:

```
void *sym = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "printf");
```

That will tell me whether the symbol `printf` exists in a loaded shared library, and if it does, what its address is, but it will not tell me which shared library it was loaded from. Is there a way to determine that?

Note I want to find the answer programatically at runtime, so solutions using debuggers, the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable, etc., are not what I am looking for.

I am particularly looking for solutions for Linux and macOS.

Comment: [dladdr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html). Note that it is a gnu extension and not in posix.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Write and accept an answer, guys?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I didn't want to rush to answer my own question, but since no one else answered it now I have

Comment: I was really suggesting that @kaylum write an answer (rather than a comment) and you accept it. But this works too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do this with the [`dladdr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) function:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <assert.h>

void show_sym(const char *sym_name) {
        void *sym_ptr = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT,sym_name);
        printf("SYMBOL %s ADDRESS %p\n", sym_name, sym_ptr);
        if (sym_ptr == NULL)
                return;
        Dl_info info;
        int rc = dladdr(sym_ptr,&info);
        assert(rc != 0);
        printf("SHARED LIBRARY NAME: %s\n", info.dli_fname);
        printf("SHARED LIBRARY BASE ADDRESS: %p\n", info.dli_fbase);
        printf("NEAREST SYMBOL: %s\n", info.dli_sname);
        printf("NEAREST SYMBOL ADDRESS: %p\n", info.dli_saddr);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s SYMBOL-NAME\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
        show_sym(argv[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

I tested the above code and it works on both macOS and Linux. (On Linux you have to link against `-ldl`.) Although I haven't tested it, the same (or similar) code likely works on other Unix-like platforms which implement `dladdr`, such as [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54766/dladdr-3c.html) (which is where `dladdr` comes from originally), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dladdr&sektion=3), [OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.3/dlfcn.3), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/dladdr.3), [DragonFly BSD](https://man.dragonflybsd.org/?command=dladdr&section=3), [HP/UX](https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/B2355-60130/dladdr.3C.html). (And the IBM mainframe operating system [z/TPF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.2020/gtpc2/cpp_dladdr.html) too, which few would call "Unix-like".)

It is possible to do the same thing on Windows, but the API is completely different (basically turn the address into a `HMODULE` using [`GetModuleHandleEx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11931884/2147204) and then call [`GetModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)). There are some other Unix-likes which support this but not using the `dladdr` API, e.g. AIX lacks `dladdr` but has an API [`loadquery`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/l_bostechref/loadquery.html) which reports at what memory addresses shared libraries are loaded and so can be indirectly used to work this out (indeed, [here](https://gist.github.com/NattyNarwhal/76190b940e5259194677875578e3349b) is some sample code to do that, although I haven't tested that code myself.)